# PowerShell Function: Hashes Called by Reference?

Tags: function, powershell, hash, pass-by-reference

I have several hashes and some functions should work with them. I want to make a call by reference for these hashes (do I need that):

```
$H1 = @{...}
$H2 = @{...}
$H3 = @{...}
...

function manage{ param( [ref]$a, [ref]$b, [ref]$c )
    ...
}

manage $H1 $H2 $H3
```

But this seems not to work. How do I do this correctly?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hashes are considered reference types in PowerShell and are always being passed by reference so no need to use `[ref]` here. What exactly doesn't work? Do you get an error or some unexpected output or behavior?

Comment: I get an error (my translation): The Argumenttraformation for the parameter $a cannot be done. A ref. is expected. I tried as well to call: manage [ref]$H1 [ref]$H2 [ref]$H3

Comment: Try without the `[ref]` then, or using `[hashtable]` specifically: `function manage { param ( [hashtable] $a, [hashtable] $b, ... ) ... }`.

Comment: And I can be SURE that if I change some values and and delete some key-vlaue-pairs it still present after the function has finished?

Comment: Yes, when you work with a hash reference inside the function the changes are done on the underlying object and will be visible outside the function via the original reference. So does it work this way? If yes I'm adding an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hashes are considered reference types in PowerShell and are always being passed by reference so no need to use `[ref]` in the params here, see [about_Ref](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847792.aspx).

Try without the `[ref]`, or using `[hashtable]` type specifically:

```
function manage {
    param (
        [hashtable] $a,
        [hashtable] $b,
        [hashtable] $c
    )
    ...
}
```

The changes you make to the hashes using the `$a`, `$b`, `$c` references inside the function will be done on the underlying hash objects and will be visible outside the function via the original `$H1`, `$H2`, `$H3` references.